# Sum of Lagrange polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I have to  calculate $\sum_{i=0}^n x^k_i*l_i(x)$ for $k=0,1,2,...,n$ . I've proved that     $\sum_{i=0}^n l_i(x) = 1$, but I cannot figure out how it may help me calculating $\sum_{i=0}^n x^k_i*l_i(x)$ .
I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution, thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k \in \mathbb N$

Define $\displaystyle L_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^k l_i(x)$

$L_k$ is a degree $n$ polynomial such that $\forall i \in \{0,\ldots,n\},L_k(x_i)=x_i^k$

Consider the polynomial $L_k-X^k$

It has degree less than $n$, and it has also $n+1$ roots.

Therefore,  $L_k=X^k$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've edited the question - it's $x^k_i$, not $x^k$

Comment: @itamar I edited as well.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this should also work. With Lagrange formular we have $f(x) - p_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}w_{n+1}(x)$ where $w_{n+1}(x) = (x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdot \dots \cdot (x-x_n)$. Let $f(x) := x^k$ then $f^{(n+1)}(\xi) = 0$ since $k \leq n$. Therefore: $L_k(x) = x^k$. Of course G.T.R's solution is a lot faster.

Comment: @fbloni I don't know if OP has covered this formula yet, but your solution is valid.